# D3.js Smooth transition from line to arc?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, css-animations

Note there is a similar - but distinct - question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434127/d3-js-smooth-transition-on-arc-draw-for-pie-chart).

**goal**: I am trying to get a straight line to move over and then wrap into an arc.

A JSFiddle of my attempt is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/s688hzmh/)

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var myPath = svg.append("path")
.attr("id", "myPath")
.attr("d", "M0 50, l 25 0")
.attr("stroke", "black")
.attr("fill", "none")
myPath.transition().duration(2000).attr("transform", "translate(100, 0)")
myPath.transition().delay(2000).duration(2000).attr("d", "M 125 143.30127018922192 A 50 50 0 0 0 100 50")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="d3-visualization-container">
    <svg width="500" height="500" style=";border:1px lightgray solid;"/>
</div>
```

However just chaining transitions doesn't get me quite there and I do not want to use d3.arc if I do not have too.

Thoughts?